# Forbidden Angular 2 in Apache 2.4 on Centos 7

Tags: apache, angular, centos7

I try to deploy [Angular 2 Webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) in my server centos 7 with Apache 2.4 but when i enter to the server domain ip from my laptop browser that send me a forbidden message.

Well the Angular 2 webpack was installed in /var/www/html/ directory and the document root from httpd.conf file is /var/www/html/src/ where are the index.html Angular 2 and i have the following config in httpd.conf file

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Pls Help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need build your app with command

```
# production (jit)
npm run build:prod
# AoT
npm run build:aot
```

after built successful, you got `dist` directory, you can rename it, then copy to html dir in /var/www/html

config apache with same config in your post.

Comment: Thanks it works !!, but i set to default config the document root in httpd.conf.

Comment: Glad to hear that.